# Linq to Entites 6, Many-to-many relationship, Selecting Fields from Both tables into an object

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6, many-to-many

I've spent the afternoon on StackOverflow and Google looking for a way to do a simple SQL query using linq to entities.  I am trying to get data from two tables joined by a many-to-many relationship.  In SQL I would write the query like this:

```
   SELECT v.[VendorID]
    , t.[UnitNumber]
    , t.[Name]
    , t.[Address]
    , t.[CityStateZip]
FROM [Tenant] t
INNER JOIN [TenantVendor] tv ON tv.[TenantID] = t.[TenantID]
INNER JOIN [Vendor] v on v.[VendorID] = tv.[VendorID]
WHERE t.[UnitNumber] LIKE '%100A%'
    AND t.[CompanyID] = 17874;
```

I have an object in a list that I'm selecting the data into that looks like this which gets applied directly to a grid:

```
public class SearchObject
    {
        public int IDField { get; set; }
        public string UniqueField { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string CityStateZip { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's the kicker, the m2m table is only made up of the primary keys from both tables, so it doesn't have an entity to select.  They show up under each others entity as a collection like this (from the tenants entity):

```
public virtual ICollection<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
```

I would prefer lambda expressions, but query would work fine too.  The closest I have got are these two:

```
SearchData = DBContext.Tenants
             .Where(t => t.Company.Name == CompanyName && t.UnitNumber.ToString().Contains(SearchText))                            
             .OrderBy(DynamicSort)
             .Skip(StartRow)
             .Take(PageSize)
             .Select(t => new SearchObject { IDField = t.Vendors, UniqueField = t.UnitNumber.ToString(), Name = t.Name, Address = t.Address, CityStateZip = t.CityStateZip })
             .ToList();
```

That one doesn't work because t.Vendors is a collection, what I want is just the vendorID.

This one works but returns way too many records since it's missing the join between the two tables:

```
SearchData = (from t in DBContext.Tenants
              from v in DBContext.Vendors
              where t.Company.Name == CompanyName && t.UnitNumber.ToString().Contains(SearchText) 
              select new SearchObject { IDField = v.VendorID , UniqueField = t.UnitNumber.ToString(), Name = t.Name, Address = t.Address, CityStateZip = t.CityStateZip })
              .ToList();
```

**EDIT / UPDATE**
After ElMent provieded me with the correct answer, I figured out how to achieve the same result using C# methods, SelectMany was the key.

```
SearchData = DBContext.Tenants
    .Where(t => t.Company.Name == CompanyName && t.UnitNumber.ToString().Contains(SearchText))
    .OrderBy(DynamicSort)
    .Skip(StartRow)
    .Take(PageSize)
    .SelectMany(t=>t.Vendors.Select(v => new SearchObject { IDField = v.VendorID, UniqueField = t.UnitNumber.ToString() + " - " + v.VendorNumber, Name = t.Name, Address = t.Address, CityStateZip = t.CityStateZip }))                                                                                                        
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this. See "from v in t.Vendors" on second line.

```
SearchData = (from t in DBContext.Tenants
                                 from v in t.Vendors
                                 where t.Company.Name == CompanyName && t.UnitNumber.ToString().Contains(SearchText) 
                                select new SearchObject { IDField = v.VendorID , UniqueField = t.UnitNumber.ToString(), Name = t.Name, Address = t.Address, CityStateZip = t.CityStateZip })
                                .ToList();
```

Mor info here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386932(v=vs.110).aspx